# Error en recursividad

Tags: java, algoritmos, recursión

Tengo el siguiente árbol de categorías donde tengo la descripción y el código de cada categoría, necesito obtener la categoría en base a la descripción a N nivel de profundidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi método recursivo es el siguiente:

```
private Category findCategory(String categoryName, String rootCategoryCode) {
    Category rootCategory = getCategoryService().getCategoryForCode( rootCategoryCode);
    if(rootCategory.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(categoryName)) {
        return rootCategory;
    } else {
        Collection<Category> subCategories = rootCategory.getCategories();
        for (Category subCategory : subCategories) {
            if (subCategory != null && !StringUtils.isBlank(subCategory.getName())) {               
                if(categoryName.equalsIgnoreCase(subCategory.getName())) {
                    return subCategory;
                } else {                   
                    findCategory(categoryName subCategory.getCode());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Y realizo la búsqueda de la siguiente forma

```
public void main(String[] args) {
      Category cat = findCategory("Sala y Biblioteca","1000000");
      System.out.println(cat.getName());
}
```

el método `getCategories()` obtiene todas las categorías que están en el siguiente nivel (Nodos hijos). Mi problema es que después de encontrar la categoría deseada ("Sala y Biblioteca") para este ejemplo me regresa siempre null ya que sigue buscando en los nodos hijos de premios y al no encontrar nada se va al return null del final del método por la recursividad. No encuentro la forma de hacer que se detenga la recursividad al encontrar la primer categoría que coincida con la descripción enviada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comentas es normal que te regrese null, ya que en el ejemplo que pones se encuentra en la primera subcategoria, pero como no tienes ninguna condición de parada simplemente va a seguir. Por lo tanto lo que te hace falta es una condición para no seguir en el bucle y lo más sencillo es ver si findCategory te devuelve null o te devuelve una categoría, ya que si devuelve una categoría no tienes que seguir.

```
private Category findCategory(String categoryName, String rootCategoryCode) {
    Category rootCategory = getCategoryService().getCategoryForCode( rootCategoryCode);
    if(rootCategory.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(categoryName)) {
        return rootCategory;
    } 

    Collection<Category> subCategories = rootCategory.getCategories();
    Category resultCategory = null;
    for (Category subCategory : subCategories) {
        if (subCategory != null && !StringUtils.isBlank(subCategory.getName())) {               
            if(categoryName.equalsIgnoreCase(subCategory.getName())) {
                resultCategory = subCategory;
            } else {                   
                resultCategory = findCategory(categoryName subCategory.getCode());
            }
        }

        if (resultCategory != null)
            break;
    }

    return resultCategory;
}
```

Espero que te funcione.